# WordPress custom menu links

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom theme WordPress but I am having some issues..
This is how I call my custom menu.

```
function wislow_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support('menus');

    register_nav_menu('primary', 'Primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary', 'Footer Navigation');
}
add_action('init', 'wislow_theme_setup');
```

Here is how I implement in my header file.

```
<body <?php body_class(array()); ?>>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary']); ?>
```

The problem though is when I try to use one of the links I am being directed to an empty page, and the pages do have content within.

Answer (score 1):

please make sure menu location selection

**Dashboard > Menus > Manage Locations**

and select primary menu which you created menu.

Answer (score 1):

wp_nav_menu function use like this : 
**wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'primary'));**